# How to use hibernate <join><any>?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm reading hibernate reference, they're two elements in Hibernate: `<join><any>`. After reading it, I don't know what the reference is talking about.

I don't understand when to use join/any, what kind of scenarios are they suitable for? For <join/>: when setting "fetch", when will hibernate use inner join, when will use outer join, when will use select? Which tables which columns are used? And for the example hibernate reference provided, it said:
<join table="ADDRESS"> <key column="ADDRESS_ID"/> <property name="address"/> <property name="zip"/> <property name="country"/> </join>, then which column is used to join these two tables?

When setting fetch for <join>, it said:
fetch (optional - defaults to join): If set to join, the default, Hibernate will use an inner join to retrieve a <join> defined by a class(My question: Would anybody please give me an example to say: which is this class?) or its superclasses((My question: Would anybody please give me an example to say: which is this class?) ) and an outer join for a <join> defined by a subclass((My question: Would anybody please give me an example to say: which is this class?) ). If set to select then Hibernate will use a sequential select for a <join> defined on a subclass((My question: Would anybody please give me an example to say: which is this class?)), which will be issued only if a row turns out to represent an instance of the subclass((My question: Would anybody please give me an example to say: which is this class?)). Inner joins will still be used to retrieve a  defined by the class and its superclasses((My question: Would anybody please give me an example to say: which is this class?) ).

In other words, I want to know what are all the classes said below:
fetch (optional - defaults to join): If set to join, the default, Hibernate will use an inner join to retrieve a <join> defined by a class or its superclasses and an outer join for a <join> defined by a subclass. If set to select then Hibernate will use a sequential select for a <join> defined on a subclass, which will be issued only if a row turns out to represent an instance of the subclass. Inner joins will still be used to retrieve a <join> defined by the class and its superclasses.

For <any>, what kind of scenarios is it suitable for?, would u please explain how it works? Is there anybody providing example and explaining this to me? Thanks.

Comment: You are dumping whole paragraph with examples etc.  How should other know which part you are having problem in understanding?  Do you expect other people able to write in a even more detailed way than the original book, and for that you can understand?  Please be precise on your question

Comment: `throw new TooManyQuestionsException();`

Comment: Sorry for that. Still hope somebody can help resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `<join>` is used to map one class two 2+ tables which have a one-to-one association over the primarykey/id

  ```
  Table A        Table B
  -------        -------
  id | name      a_id | status

  class Foo
  {
      private int id;
      private string name;
      private string status;
  }

  <class name="Foo">
    <id name="id"/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <join table="B">
      <key column="a_id"/>
      <property name="status"/>
    </join>
  </class>
  ```
- `<any>` is used to map a polymorphic reference e.g. a contact can reference a User or a Company it belongs to. So it uses two columns: one the id of Company/User and a second to store the type of the reference e.g. "user" or "company". The advantage is that it knows the type (and table) of the referenced entity without the need to look into all possible tables

  ```
  Table Users         Table Companies
  ----------          -------------
  id | name           id | trademark

  Table Contacts
  -----------------------
  id | text | owner_id | owner_type

  class User/Company implements HasContacts
  {
      private int id;
      private string name/trademark;
      private Set<Contact> contacts;
  }

  class Contact
  {
      private int id;
      private string text;
      private HasContacts owner;
  }

  <class name="Contact">
    <id name="id"/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <any name="owner" id-type="System.Int64" meta-type="System.String">
      <meta-value value="user" class="User"/>
      <meta-value value="company" class="Company"/>
      <column name="owner_id"/>
      <column name="owner_type"/>
    </any>
  </class>

  <class name="User">
    <id name="id"/>
    <property name="name"/>
    <set name="contacts" where="owner_type='user'">
      <key column="owner_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="Contact"/>
    </set>
  </class>

  <class name="Company">
    <id name="id"/>
    <property name="trademark"/>
    <set name="contacts" where="owner_type='company'">
      <key column="owner_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="Contact"/>
    </set>
  </class>
  ```

Comment: Great thanks for replying. Would u please give example of join and any, in which it contains java class, xml file(or metadata), table ddl?

Comment: have added some simple examples

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing, it's really great helpful. For join, in hibernate reference, when talking about join's option "fetch", it said a lot about superclass, subclass, I don't know what it means, can you help explain this? In other words, I want to know what are all the "class" said below: fetch (optional - defaults to join): If set to join, the default, Hibernate will use an inner join to retrieve a <join> defined by a class or its superclasses and an outer join for a <join> defined by a subclass(Pls check the next comment because it exceeds the character count allowed in comment).

Comment: If set to select then Hibernate will use a sequential select for a <join> defined on a subclass, which will be issued only if a row turns out to represent an instance of the subclass. Inner joins will still be used to retrieve a <join> defined by the class and its superclasses.

Comment: ftechmode defines how the entry of Table B is gathered either using a join with Table A or a seperate select using the id from table A as restriction.

Comment: Then what does the subclass, superclass mean in hibernate reference document which I mentioned above? Do they mean extend relationship, such as Class B extends Class A?

Comment: it describes the small differences between a <join> in a normal/base class and <join> in a joined subclass

Comment: I knew <joined-subclass> can be used to map subclass. Can u give an example on how <join> is mapped in subclass? Maybe with java class, xml file(or metadata), table ddl? Sorry for so many questions, and appreciate all ur help.